# Trying to get my video card info - but I see very general brand name

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card

I was trying to determine what kind of graphic card I have but this is what I have you can [see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdI35.png) it is very general:  AMD Radeon TM Graphic. Is there a way I can get more info?

Comment: Call up Device Manager and look at your hardware there - it will have a lot more detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can use HWiNFO https://www.hwinfo.com/download/

HWiNFO is a System Information and Diagnostics Tool. HWInfo64 is an application that monitors your PC's components and outputs computer information about your operating system, storage capacity, and RAM. It also displays more technical data, such as the number of logical CPUs, memory speed, and temperatures.